# Taggable Friends list of facebook

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

Can any one tell me that, is the id of taggable friends are dynamic in nature? Why I am saying is, each and every time when I run the program to collect my facebook taggable friends using

```
get('/me/taggable_friends?fields=name&limit=100')
```

I got different id's [Like the set of id's are attached here set-1 http://pastebin.com/fjUmCgJY and set-2 http://pastebin.com/RpTZswc6 for same set of taggable friends] while running the following code two time.

```
if ($fb->next($friends)) {
        $allFriends = array();
        $friendsArray = $friends->asArray();
        $allFriends = array_merge($friendsArray, $allFriends);
        while ($friends = $fb->next($friends)) {
            $friendsArray = $friends->asArray();
            $allFriends = array_merge($friendsArray, $allFriends);
        }
        $array1 = json_encode($allFriends, true);
        //foreach ($allFriends as $key) {
            //echo $key['name'] . "<br>";
        //}
        echo ($array1);
        //echo count($allFriends);
    } else {
        $allFriends = $friends->asArray();
        $totalFriends = count($allFriends);
        $array1 = json_encode($allFriends, true);
        /*foreach ($allFriends as $key) {
            echo $key['name'] . "<br>";
        }*/
        echo ($array1);

    }
```

Another observation is that, while executing my code, sometimes I got the result but some times I got

```
Fatal error: Call to a member function bind_param() on boolean in
```

What is the reason?

Comment: Those are not ids, but short-lived tokens only. So that you get different tokens for the same friends for different requests, is normal.

Comment: @CBroe, is there any chance to get the user id of taggable friends?

Comment: No, of course not. That endpoint is for tagging people in Open graph stories _only_ – so don’t try to abuse it for any other purpose.

Comment: @Anupam `taggable_friends` is explicitly designed to prevent you from getting information on a user's friends if they don't also use the app. Don't try to work around this limit, it'll just get you banned.

Comment: @ceejayoz, Is this same if I use this app as a "tester mode"?

Comment: @Anupam An app in tester mode that violates the TOS can still get you in trouble. Use the APIs as they're intended.

Comment: @ceejayoz, Actually, during the survey, I intend get the survey as well as the user's taggable friends list plus id. As now I understood that it is not possible to get the id, I 'll limit myself to name only. Hope in this case FB dint have any problem and the whole app will be in test mode for selected user

Comment: what do you want to do with the name? you are ONLY allowed to use the taggable_friends for tagging. don´t use it for anything else.

Comment: @luschn, name needed for educational research purpose.

Comment: @Anupam Not permitted. If Facebook catches you, your app will be disabled.

Answer (score 2):

You only get a "Tagging Token" with `taggable_friends`, there is no way to get a User ID. You are only allowed to use `taggable_friends` for tagging, so there is no need to get a User ID anyway.

If you want to get access to friends for something else, i suggest reading the answer in this thread: [Facebook Graph Api v2.0+ - /me/friends returns empty, or only friends who also use my app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23417356/facebook-graph-api-v2-0-me-friends-returns-empty-or-only-friends-who-also-u)